# How to translate this simple C# method that use XPath into a Java method?

Tags: c#, java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I am pretty new in the use of **XPath** in **Java** and I don't know **C#**.

In this time I have to convert some **C#** methods that use **XPath** into **Java** methods and I have some doubts about it.

In a C# method I found the following lines of code:

```
System.Xml.XmlNode element;
System.Xml.XmlNode filter;

filter = _document.CreateElement("filter");
element = _document.CreateElement("name");
element.InnerText = es.Descrizione;
filter.AppendChild(element);
```

and I am trying to convert it into Java code.

I think that the first 2 lines can be translated as:

```
Element element;
Element filter;
```

(it is simple a declaration of a Jdom Element objects)

But I have many doubts about how translate these lines in Java:

```
filter = _document.CreateElement("filter");
element = _document.CreateElement("name");

filter.AppendChild(element);
```

Can you help me?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: Firstly, your C# code does not use XPath. It only uses DOM methods. Secondly, in Java you have a choice of tree models: DOM, JDOM, XOM, DOM4J. You've hinted that you want to use JDOM (which is probably a good choice) but you'll get confusing answers because you haven't really made this clear.

Answer (score 0):

The Java equivalent would be the following:

```
import javax.xml.parsers.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Element element;                            // System.Xml.XmlNode element;
        Element filter;                             // System.Xml.XmlNode filter;

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document _document = db.newDocument();
        filter = _document.createElement("filter"); // filter = _document.CreateElement("filter");
        element = _document.createElement("name");  // element = _document.CreateElement("name");
        element.setTextContent(es.Descrizione);     // element.InnerText = es.Descrizione;
        filter.appendChild(element);                // filter.AppendChild(element);
        _document.appendChild(filter);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you mentioning XPath? I don't see any use of it. If you want to continue to use the DOM API then you could do that even in Java with http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/package-summary.html and your code would be

```
import org.w3c.dom;


Element element;
Element filter;

filter = _document.createElement("filter");
element = _document.createElement("name");
element.setTextContent(es.Descrizione);
filter.appendChild(element);
```

If you want to use JDOM then you would need to change the approach and instead of using the DOM based factory methods like `document.createElement(..)` you would simply use constructor methods like `new Element(..)`.

Comment: mmm I am importing org.jdom.* package and not org.w3c.dom, I don't know it this is the same thing. By the way I am trying to do something like you suggest me but can't work, I have do:

Document document = new Document();
filter = document.createElement("filter");

but now Eclipse say to me the following error message: "The method createElement(String) is undefined for the type Document"
Why?

Comment: @AndreaNobili, W3C DOM and JDOM are different object models and you need to decide which one you want to use. You seem to use JDOM in Java but as you are trying to convert C# code using the DOM in .NET it might be easier to use DOM in Java as well. It's your choice. And if you choose JDOM then of course you have to use the JDOM API. All those `createXXX` methods on the document are part of the W3C DOM, the JDOM intentionally uses a different approach and provides constructor methods like `new Element(..)` to construct an element node. So decide which object model and which API you want to use.